# PHP GET request from an API with a client-id without the usage of cURL

Tags: php, api, get, request

I have to send a GET Request within a PHP Script to get data from an API with a certain given client-id without the usage of cURL.

In the terminal I use following command:

```
curl -i -u “123456-123ea-123-123-123456789:“-H “Content-Type: 
application/json” -X GET 
“https://api.aHoster.io/api/rest/jobboards/jobs”
```

(123456-123ea-123-123-123456789 in this command is the given client-id I got)

Everything works fine in the terminal, but now I like to do this GET request in a php script.

How do I add the client-id in this attempt?

```
<?php
$url = 'https://api.aHoster.io/api/rest/jobboards/jobs';
$client_id = '123456-123ea-123-123-123456789';

$options = array(
  'http' => array(
      'header'  => "Content-type: application/json\r\n",
      'method'  => 'GET',
 )
);
$context = stream_context_create($options);
$result = @file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

if ($http_response_header[0] == "HTTP/1.1 200 OK") {
  //...
} else { 
  // ...
}
?>
```

Comment: What happens and why suppress errors with `@`?

Comment: why not (php) curl? its installed by default so ... or you could even call your command line curl from php if you really wanted to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your cURL command you want to add an Authorization header:

```
$options = array(
  'http' => array(
      'header'  => "Content-type: application/json\r\n" .
                   "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode($client_id) . "\r\n",
      'method'  => 'GET',
 )
);
```

I'm not sure but you may need a colon showing empty password `"$client_id:"`.

Also, do a `print_r($http_response_header);` afterwards as it may contain information such as `"Authorization Required"` or something else useful.

Comment: Did it require the `:`?

Comment: Nope, it didn't.